# What are the programs/commands which the magic SysRq key invoke?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, keyboard-shortcuts, magic-sysrq

From [Magic SysRq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

> The magic SysRq key is a key combination understood by the Linux
>   kernel, which allows the user to perform various **low level commands**
>   regardless of the system's state. It is often used to recover from
>   freezes, or to reboot a computer without corrupting the filesystem.

What are the low level commands which [the keys in the table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Commands) invoke?

Are they  programs that can run in terminal?

How different are the keys from those shortcut keys for gnome or unity?

Comment: I just removed thanks from two posts you posted today. From your top 10 posts "thanks" in some form or another had to be removed  by 7 different people. Please stop including this irrelevant material (read [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour): no distractions, no chit-chat). so we can focus on answering questions instead of correcting yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In the linux kernel source code in [sysrq.c at line 415](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/sysrq.c#L415), there is a struct defined, what should happen when a certain key is pressed. So you see, no command in a terminal is excuted, instead of this, hard coded functions in the kernel are called. So, as long as the kernel is not crashed, you can press those keys, doesn't matter which application is running in the foreground, the kernel handles the keys pressed.

Here is the interessing part:

```
[...]
415 static struct sysrq_key_op *sysrq_key_table[36] = {
416         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 0 */
417         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 1 */
418         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 2 */
419         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 3 */
420         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 4 */
421         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 5 */
422         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 6 */
423         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 7 */
424         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 8 */
425         &sysrq_loglevel_op,             /* 9 */
426 
427         /*
428          * a: Don't use for system provided sysrqs, it is handled specially on
429          * sparc and will never arrive.
430          */
431         NULL,                           /* a */
432         &sysrq_reboot_op,               /* b */
433         &sysrq_crash_op,                /* c & ibm_emac driver debug */
434         &sysrq_showlocks_op,            /* d */
435         &sysrq_term_op,                 /* e */
436         &sysrq_moom_op,                 /* f */
437         /* g: May be registered for the kernel debugger */
438         NULL,                           /* g */
439         NULL,                           /* h - reserved for help */
440         &sysrq_kill_op,                 /* i */
441 #ifdef CONFIG_BLOCK
442         &sysrq_thaw_op,                 /* j */
443 #else
444         NULL,                           /* j */
445 #endif
446         &sysrq_SAK_op,                  /* k */
447 #ifdef CONFIG_SMP
448         &sysrq_showallcpus_op,          /* l */
449 #else
450         NULL,                           /* l */
451 #endif
452         &sysrq_showmem_op,              /* m */
453         &sysrq_unrt_op,                 /* n */
454         /* o: This will often be registered as 'Off' at init time */
455         NULL,                           /* o */
456         &sysrq_showregs_op,             /* p */
457         &sysrq_show_timers_op,          /* q */
458         &sysrq_unraw_op,                /* r */
459         &sysrq_sync_op,                 /* s */
460         &sysrq_showstate_op,            /* t */
461         &sysrq_mountro_op,              /* u */
462         /* v: May be registered for frame buffer console restore */
463         NULL,                           /* v */
464         &sysrq_showstate_blocked_op,    /* w */
465         /* x: May be registered on ppc/powerpc for xmon */
466         /* x: May be registered on sparc64 for global PMU dump */
467         NULL,                           /* x */
468         /* y: May be registered on sparc64 for global register dump */
469         NULL,                           /* y */
470         &sysrq_ftrace_dump_op,          /* z */
471 };
[...]
```

Technically you can call them also in a terminal But, you write in a pseudo-file in the proc filesystem called `/proc/sysrq-trigger`. For example you can do a:

```
echo b >/proc/sysrq-trigger
```

... which instantly reboots the machine, without asking or warning or anything. It's the same as when you press <kbd>SysRq</kbd> - <kbd>b</kbd>.

Comment: For me, `/proc/sysrq-trigger` is 0200, so you'll need a `sudo` there.

Answer (score 2):

*as linked in the wikipedia article in external links* ... you can see that documentation here: [Linux Magic System Request Key Hacks](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt)

*edit*:

this is also found in Linux kernel source under the `Documentation` subdirectory

Comment: thanks. how different are they from those shortcut keys for gnome or unity?

Comment: the kernel executes these

Comment: Do they invoke programs runnable on terminal?

Comment: they do not invoke any programs in user space .... they are done intermally in the kernel if the kernel is still running

Comment: the programs they invoke are part of the kernel? Not executable files?